# Disk drive suddenly restarts and gets removed from the RAID

Tags: linux, mdadm, software-raid, smartctl

We have a couple of servers with 6 HDDs in software RAID6.
Recently one of the servers has started to experience performance issues and I have noticed that one of the disk drives got removed from the RAID.
I've re-added it with mdadm, it got re-synced and everything went back to normal, but it keeps happening every few hours.

Disk gets removed from the RAID, mdadm shows the RAID status as degraded. The device start/stop count gets increased by 1 (in smartctl). Also the device changes from sdc to sdg and back.
So I'm not quite sure how to debug the issue or how to prevent that.
Does that mean that the disk is faulty and we should ask our hoster to replace it? Or is it a software issue?

Comment: Make and (full) model number of the disk at fault please. (I'm particularly interested to know if the disk is SMR or CMR.)

Comment: @roaima it's HGST HUH721212ALE601

Comment: Good it's CMR and not SMR. That's one possibility out of the way

Comment: Does `smartctl -a /dev/sdX` (for the correct value of `X`) bring up any warnings?

Comment: @roaima no warnings, nothing. There are "3 offline uncorrectable" errors for another drive, but this one seems to be fine according to the smartctl.